# How to merge two adjacent XML elements having same class?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML node like the following:

```
<p>
Lorem <span class="red">ipsu</span><span class="red">m</span> dolor sit amet,
<span class="green">consectetur</span><span class="bold">adipiscingelit</span>.
</p>
```

Observe that the word "ipsum" is seperated into two similar span tags. I want to merge such elements into something like `<span class="red">ipsum</span>`. If two adjacent spans have different classes, they must remain as they are.

How can I do that with C#?

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: I don't know any starting point to try something. 
If a get elements by class name, I can't know whether the elements are adjacent. If I find and replace `</span><span class="red">` with regex, I can't be sure if `</span>` belongs to similar kind of span.

Comment: I didn't try XSLT. Can I solve my problem with XSLT? I just tried System.XML library in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq to XML (a little clunky):

```
//elem is an XElement containing the XML
var duplicateRanges = (
    from head in elem.Elements()
    let currentClass = (string)head.Attribute("class")
    let others = head.ElementsAfterSelf().TakeWhile(next => {
        if (next.NodesBeforeSelf().LastOrDefault().NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) { return false; }
        return (string)next.Attribute("class") == currentClass;
    })
    where others.Any()
    select new {
        head,
        others
    }).ToList();
foreach (var range in duplicateRanges) {
    range.head.Value=(string)range.head + String.Join("", from o in range.others select (string)o);
    foreach (var other in range.others) {
        other.Remove();
    }
}
```

This may be sufficient for your purposes, but it has a major limitation: it will destroy any child nodes in the spans to be removed. Only the text will be preserved and merged with the first span.